# Split specific column in data frame in R

Tags: r, stringr

I am working with R. Below you can see my code and my data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  R1 = c("10 EFTA : 0 / BAA/GBR : 0 / ES : 2", "10","0"),
  R2 = c("-", "EFTA : 0 / BAA/GBR : 0 / ES : 2","18")
)
```

[image]

Now I want to split first column R1. At the beginning I want to split first row with following command:

```
df[c('R1', 'R2')] <- str_split_fixed(df$R1, ' ', 2)
```

This line split first row exactly that I needed and below you can see how is look like a data frame now.

[image]

But problem arise with next rows. Namely, now you can see that this value `"EFTA : 0 / BAA/GBR : 0 / ES : 2"` and also in the next row value `18` is missing.
So can anybody help me how to solve this problem and to have df like df shown below :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first find matching rows and then only process those matches:

```r
library(stringr)
df <- data.frame(
  R1 = c("10 EFTA : 0 / BAA/GBR : 0 / ES : 2", "10","0"),
  R2 = c("-", "EFTA : 0 / BAA/GBR : 0 / ES : 2","18")
)
df
#>                                   R1                              R2
#> 1 10 EFTA : 0 / BAA/GBR : 0 / ES : 2                               -
#> 2                                 10 EFTA : 0 / BAA/GBR : 0 / ES : 2
#> 3                                  0                              18

# boolean index to match rows where R1 includes " ":
spaces_in_r1 <- str_detect(df$R1, fixed(" "))
spaces_in_r1
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE

df[spaces_in_r1 ,c('R1', 'R2')] <- str_split_fixed(df$R1[spaces_in_r1], ' ', 2)
df
#>   R1                              R2
#> 1 10 EFTA : 0 / BAA/GBR : 0 / ES : 2
#> 2 10 EFTA : 0 / BAA/GBR : 0 / ES : 2
#> 3  0                              18
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm when to choose what is not very well-defined but based on your desired output something like the code below might work?

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  R1 = c("10 EFTA : 0 / BAA/GBR : 0 / ES : 2", "10","0"),
  R2 = c("-", "EFTA : 0 / BAA/GBR : 0 / ES : 2","18")
)

df |> 
  separate_wider_regex(
    R1,
    patterns = c(digits = "^\\d+", "(?:\\s+)?", rest = ".*")
  ) |> 
  mutate(rest = if_else(rest == "", R2, rest),
         .keep = "unused")
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   digits rest                           
#>   <chr>  <chr>                          
#> 1 10     EFTA : 0 / BAA/GBR : 0 / ES : 2
#> 2 10     EFTA : 0 / BAA/GBR : 0 / ES : 2
#> 3 0      18
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>