# Replace specific values in data frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

Below you can see my data.

```
df <- data.frame(
  R1 = c("EFTA : 0 / BAA/GBR : 0 / ES : 2", "10","EFTA : 0 / BAA/GBR : 0 / ES : 2","NA"),
  R2 = c("-", "EFTA : 0 / BAA/GBR : 0 / ES : 2","NA","CEFTA : 0 / MSA/GB : 0 / TR : 0")
)
```

[image]

Now I want to replace value from column R1 into column R2, but only if values in R2 are "-" or "NA". Final output that I expect is shown in table below.

[image]

So please can anybody help me to solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(R2 = replace(R2, R2 %in% c("-", "NA"), NA),
         R2 = coalesce(R2, R1),
         R1 = ifelse(R1 == R2, "", R1))
```

By using `replace` to turn those values into `NA`, we can then use `coalesce` to replace `NA` values when there is a value in `R1`.

**Output**

```
  R1                              R2
1    EFTA : 0 / BAA/GBR : 0 / ES : 2
2 10 EFTA : 0 / BAA/GBR : 0 / ES : 2
3    EFTA : 0 / BAA/GBR : 0 / ES : 2
4 NA CEFTA : 0 / MSA/GB : 0 / TR : 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Using base R you could do

```
within(df, {
          SWAP <- R2=="NA" | R2=="-"
          R2 <- ifelse(SWAP, R1, R2)
          R1 <- ifelse(SWAP, "", R1)
          SWAP <- NULL
})
```

Just create a variable indicating if the swap should happen, then use `ifelse` to swap columns. Note the order of the swaps matter because the variables will immediately change. The last SWAP<-NULL removes it from the output.

It woudl be similar with `dplyr`

```
dplyr::mutate(df, 
    SWAP = R2=="NA" | R2=="-",
    R2 = if_else(SWAP, R1, R2),
    R1 = if_else(SWAP, "", R1),
    SWAP = NULL)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to match the pattern used for your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77260504/split-specific-column-in-data-frame-in-r), locate rows & swap columns:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  R1 = c("EFTA : 0 / BAA/GBR : 0 / ES : 2", "10","EFTA : 0 / BAA/GBR : 0 / ES : 2","NA"),
  R2 = c("-", "EFTA : 0 / BAA/GBR : 0 / ES : 2","NA","CEFTA : 0 / MSA/GB : 0 / TR : 0")
)

to_swap <- df$R2 %in% c("-", "NA")
to_swap
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

df[to_swap, c("R1", "R2")] <- df[to_swap, c("R2", "R1")]
df
#>   R1                              R2
#> 1  - EFTA : 0 / BAA/GBR : 0 / ES : 2
#> 2 10 EFTA : 0 / BAA/GBR : 0 / ES : 2
#> 3 NA EFTA : 0 / BAA/GBR : 0 / ES : 2
#> 4 NA CEFTA : 0 / MSA/GB : 0 / TR : 0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>